Running Quarkus test with reactive messaging and get java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CDI container is available
I am trying to learn quarkus-messaging-amqp and that is why I created a very simple project where I have one consumer which has @Incoming("executor-in") annotation where I log what was consumed (Executor object). I also created MessageConverter where I convert from Json string to object (Executor). Now when I send serialized Executor object inside my Junit 5 test I get  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CDI container is available which I do not know why. This happens if I run the test inside Intellij.
UPDATE
One important thing is that the test is working but method for message consuming is not being called.
The funny thing is that if I do not convert Json to Executor (inside MessageConverter class) object and just resend Message<?> with Json payload and change method argument from Executor to String then everything works
To not too much pollute the space with the code I also attach link to project on GitHub: link
Thanks for any help in advance.

The answer can be found on GitHub here. The problem was following (answer from GitHub by Ladicek user):

... This is because your test sends the message and immediately stops; it
doesn't wait for the processing to finish. When Quarkus stops, an
exception like this can happen very easily (as well as a bunch of
other exceptions). If you for example add Thread.sleep(5000) to the
end of the @Test method, the exception isn't thrown. ...


I've ran you code and error is after shutdown
ERROR: SRMSG00200: The method onMessage has thrown an exception [Error Occurred After Shutdown]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CDI container is available
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcCDIProvider.getCDI(ArcCDIProvider.java:29)
    at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:77)
    at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:64)
    at io.smallrye.context.jta.context.propagation.JtaContextProvider.tm(JtaContextProvider.java:119)
    at io.smallrye.context.jta.context.propagation.JtaContextProvider.currentContext(JtaContextProvider.java:37)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.ThreadContextProviderPlan.takeThreadContextSnapshots(ThreadContextProviderPlan.java:72)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.SlowCapturedContextState.<init>(SlowCapturedContextState.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext.captureContext(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:763)
    at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext.contextualSupplier(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:753)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.context.BaseContextPropagationInterceptor.decorate(BaseContextPropagationInterceptor.java:28)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.infrastructure.Infrastructure.decorate(Infrastructure.java:149)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniCreate.deferred(UniCreate.java:479)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.AbstractMediator.invokeBlocking(AbstractMediator.java:189)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.SubscriberMediator.lambda$processMethodReturningVoid$0(SubscriberMediator.java:162)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.MultiOnItem.lambda$transformToUni$6(MultiOnItem.java:268)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiConcatMapOp$MainSubscriber.onItem(MultiConcatMapOp.java:117)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiMapOp$MapProcessor.onItem(MultiMapOp.java:50)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiOperatorProcessor.onItem(MultiOperatorProcessor.java:100)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.locals.ContextOperator$ContextMulti$ContextProcessor.lambda$onItem$1(ContextOperator.java:71)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.helpers.VertxContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(VertxContext.java:26)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:261)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

your test completed normally so this is just problem AFTER shutdown.
I have never used messaging but given a further look to documentation the direct usage of AmqpClient is not explained in guides.
I suppose you can report this problem in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions and wait for help.

Thanks for your hint to where to post this question. I have created discussion on github. Here is the link: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/43894.
If I will get an answer I will also put the answer here or there (wherever I get the first answer).
